# mapbox pins do not load all the time from geojson

Tags: javascript, geojson, mapbox

I have a weird issue on Mapbox with js. 
We are loading in geoJson files to get all the pins, which works fine most of the time with no errors. But every so often the json just simply does not seem to load and no pins appear.

Does not seem to be a browser specific problem, or cache or cross domain (as its from the same server and it would never work).

Guessing it could be something in our GEOJSON or js, but then it would never ever work.

Our next step is to add a callback and then try the loop again, but I was wondering if there was something simple we are overlooking in the way map box and geoJSON play together?

Comment: A link would be useful I am guessing!
[link](http://stage.phenotype.net/oddizzi/map-prototype/)

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the issue here was having a series of objects on the map from within map box (a pin, some drawn boxes). Then we load in the geojson.

So loading was not an issue, it was adding a layer that was being flatly ignored.